# mysql get row before and after sortindex

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id    sortindex
1     15
2     3
4     1
5     4
8     6
11    2
13    5
```

I want get the row before and after sortindex.

**For Example:**

I have given the id 5 (so, sortindex 4)
The table should order by sortindex (ASC)

And now I want get the row before
should return:

```
id    sortindex
2     3
```

and the row after
should return:

```
id    sortindex
13    5
```

How I must build the Query's?
(I want two Query's: one for before and one for after)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE sortindex < 4 ORDER BY sortindex DESC LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE sortindex > 4 ORDER BY sortindex ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id), sortindex
FROM table
WHERE id < @id
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN(id), sortindex
FROM table
WHERE id > @id
```